# Is it possible to find out who has voted on a particular question or comment?

Tags: discussion, voting

That's it, it's all in the title, sweet!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

Voting is anonymous and the specifics are available only to the development team.

Even moderators can't see who voted on what. And they have no reason to either.

Comment: even on the dev team we suppress the dev-only "show voting" option on posts owned by the current user, regardless. So we'd have to query the db on our own posts.

Comment: @JeffAtwood But, what's the point of keeping all those voters' name in db?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 I asusme it's so that they can track and reverse (if needed) serial voters.

Comment: @Mooz For serial vote reversal, you don't need to keep names forever.